# Using dynamic php generated images with MPDF

Tags: php, yii, mpdf

I am using php and mpdf to generate a particular pdf. I have some pie diagrams in the pdf. For that I am using pChart. I am generating pie diagrams dynamically for rendering in pdf.

In my pdf all the static images are rendered properly, but no **dynamically** generated pie diagrams.

This one(static) works,

```
<div class="chart">
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/color-block2.png', 'Logo screenshot', array('class' => 'logo_image')); ?>
</div>
```

But not this(dynamic)

```
<div class="chart">
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/pie.png', 'Logo screenshot', array('class' => 'logo_image')); ?>
</div>
```

Ps: I am using Yii url rules for a clean url for pie diagram.

When i rendered the pdf_template as html, both images are rendered properly.

How can i implement dynamic images using mpdf without the `$mpdf->Image()` method.

I suspect i cannot use the `$mpdf->Image()` while generating a pdf from html.

**Update:**

After

```
$mPDF->showImageErrors = true;
```

I'm getting

```
mPDF error: IMAGE Error (http://csrt.dev/images/pie.png): Could not find image file
```

Comment: see for examples here http://mpdf.bpm1.com/index.php?page=Examples

Comment: Please read my question.

Comment: What happens when you try yo open http://csrt.dev/images/pie.png from your browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Base64 encoded the image and embedded it in a `<img>` tag.

```
<div class="chart">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,xx5t.." />
</div>
```

I had the same problem using Yii, and found this to be the solution, however for other Yii/PHP users out there, you have to use base64_encode(your file contents) to get the part after base64, in the  tag.
for example:
    `base64_encode(file_get_contents("../images/folder16.gif"));`

Comment: That's a valid workaround. Unfortunately does not solve the original problem though. I've stumbled upon the same - seems to be an mPDF bug of some kind. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue.

Using:

```
 <img src="http://domain.com/assets/img/header.png">
```

or

```
 <img src="/assets/img/header.png">
```

give me the following error:

```
mPDF error: IMAGE Error (http://domain.com/assets/img/header.png): Could not find image file
```

Even though i can browse to that and see the image ok.

However using:

```
 <img src="assets/img/header.png">
```

Seems to work fine.